# cakeDC utils csvImport use?

Tags: csv, import, cakephp-1.3

I am looking to use the cakeDC CSVimport behaviour. However, I cannot work out how to set it up and there doesn't seem to be any documentation or instructions around. I am uploading a csv then I need to insert the data into the a MySQL table. I have the upload working as required.

NOTE: the csvimport behaviour is part of the cakeDC utils plugin: https://github.com/CakeDC/utils

I have this in my upload model

```
var $actsAs = array('Utils.CsvImport');
```

Within my upload controller I have this (after the file is uploaded successfully)

```
$this->Upload->importCSV('/maslayout/files/'. $thefilename);
```

I am then getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'SplFileObject::__construct(/maslayout/files/customers_aussievets_24092010.csv) [<a href='http://php.net/splfileobject.--construct'>splfileobject.--construct</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\app\plugins\utils\models\behaviors\csv_import.php:105 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\app\plugins\utils\models\behaviors\csv_import.php(105): SplFileObject->__construct('/maslayout/file...', 'rb') #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\cake\libs\model\model_behavior.php(169): CsvImportBehavior->importCSV(Object(Upload), '/maslayout/file...') #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\cake\libs\model\model_behavior.php(467): ModelBehavior->dispatchMethod(Object(Upload), 'importCSV', Array) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\cake\libs\model\model.php(496): BehaviorCollection->dispatchMethod(Object(Upload), 'importCSV', Array) #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\cake\libs\overloadable_php5.php(50): Model->call__('importCSV', Array) #5 E:\xampp\htdocs in E:\xampp\htdocs\maslayout\app\plugins\utils\models\behaviors\csv_import.php on line 105
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

===========================================================================

UPDATE: I worked out I simply had the path incorrect, now that I have this right it seems to be uploading however I don't really understand what to do next. I am not sure if I need to set the CSV document up somehow and how do I get the model set so the import will work and match up. Any help would be appreciated. I have it on my uploads model and this is basically insert empty rows into the uploads table. Even when I have the right headers on the form this still happens.

Answer (score 0):

You may get some help on this link:

Plugin to Import CSV in CakePHP[Utils Plugin for CakePHP not inserting records into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176139/utils-plugin-for-cakephp-not-inserting-records-into-table)

and a complete reference is given here on GitHub:
https://github.com/CakeDC/utils