# Utils Plugin for CakePHP not inserting records into table

Tags: cakephp

I am using the Utils Plugin for CakePHP on this link - https://github.com/CakeDC/utils. However the problem that i am having right now is that when i upload the csv its counting the correct number of records from my csv using setFlash e.g (Successfully imported 3 records from test.csv), but doesnt insert any records into the database. Does anyone have any idea on what might be causing this. I didnt change anything from the link provided.

These are the steps that i have taken so far. In my Appmodel i have added the code below

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Utils.CsvImport' => array(
        'delimiter'  => ','
    )
);
```

Created a share View called Common in app/View/Common and add the shared import.ctp view, code below

```
<h3>Import <?php echo Inflector::pluralize($modelClass);?> from CSV data file</h3>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create($modelClass, array('action' => 'import', 'type' => 'file') );
echo $this->Form->input('CsvFile', array('label'=>'','type'=>'file') );
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Here is my import action to AppController

```
/**
* CSV Import functionality for all controllers
*    
*/
function import() {
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
    if ( $this->request->is('POST') ) {
        $records_count = $this->$modelClass->find( 'count' );
        try {
            $this->$modelClass->importCSV( $this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['tmp_name']  );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $import_errors = $this->$modelClass->getImportErrors();
            $this->set( 'import_errors', $import_errors );
            $this->Session->setFlash( __('Error Importing') . ' ' . $this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['name'] . ', ' . __('column name mismatch.')  );
            $this->redirect( array('action'=>'import') );
        }

        $new_records_count = $this->$modelClass->find( 'count' ) - $records_count;
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully imported') . ' ' . $new_records_count .  ' records from ' . $this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['name'] );
        $this->redirect( array('action'=>'index') );
    }
    $this->set('modelClass', $modelClass );
    $this->render('../Common/import');
} //end import()
```

To upload the documents im point my app to the controller action e.g localhost/test/employees/import

Thanks in advance

Comment: I visited the link and nothing is inserted in my database as well? What browser did you use to visit the link? Ok, now serious: without knowing what your actually *doing* and any insight in *your code* (the plugin by itself does nothing, you're *using* functionality of the plugin in your code) nobody will be able to answer your question. There may be a validation-rule in your model that is blocking the save or just a typo in your controller.

Comment: @thaJeztah i have edited my question, hope its more clear now.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear what you're trying to do and puts the question in context. Did you also enable debug and checked the SQL? Did a 'rolllback' occur? Or does it give errors?